# Loading javascript on only one wordpress page

Tags: php, wordpress

Below is my code. Not sure why this isn't working. I know it's not because when I use firebug on different pages that aren't page 39, it's saying fitvids() is not a function. So it's loading on every other page.

```
<?php if (is_page ( 39 )){?>

    <script src="../js/jquery.fitvids.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

          $(document).ready(function() {

            $("#content-wrapper").fitVids();

          });

    </script>

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: As a side note, you could aswell test if #content-wrapper is existing before launching fitVids on it... but indeed loading this script only on the page it's used is the best idea.

Comment: [Due to certain global variables being overwritten during The Loop is_page() will not work](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_page) ...

Comment: Where are you inserting this code? Calls to `is_page()` won't work inside the loop.

Comment: It's in my header.php file. Inside the loop?

Comment: Inside the loops means it would be inside a post. I'm trying to load a javascript file (this needs to go in your <head> so in the header.php page). What am I missing here?